# Read/Write/Format NDEF ISO/IEC 14443A Card using libnfc

Tags: nfc, mifare, ndef, contactless-smartcard, lib-nfc

I recently bought a pn532 breakout board from adafruit and a couple of MIfare NFC 1K card. I also have a AS3955 ISO/IEC 14443A NFC tag from austria micro system with 4Kb EEPROM.

I have installed libnfc on raspberry pi and i am able to run nfc-list, nfc-poll and quick_start_example. The pn532 is interfaced to raspberry pi over uart.

Now i am trying to read, write and format the NDEF message stored NFC tag EEPROM(Data block) using libnfc. I went through libnfc documentation but i could not figure out how to do this.

Can anyone expalin how to read/write/format ndef messages from the EEPROM(Data block) and give references to functions that i can use from libnfc